# Print value returned by a function to screen in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote the following JavaScript functions :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showVariable(val){         
    if(typeof(val)!=null && typeof(val)!=false &&typeof(val)!=NaN && typeof(val)!=undefined)
        return typeof(val);
    else 
        return val;
}
function print(){
    var val = {1, 2, 3};
    var res = showVariable(val);
    alert(res);
}
</script>
```

Currently, I can see the result using alert, but I want to know if there is another method to print `showVariable`'s result in my html document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have pointed out how to add text to an existing HTML element. A couple other options are described below.

**Error log**

For debugging, an alternative to `alert()` that's less intrusive is to add the text to the error log. For instance, in Firefox with the Firebug extension:

```
if (console.log) console.log(res);
```

**Document.write**

Another option that probably won't apply to this particular question, but which is sometimes helpful, is to use `document.write`. Be careful not to use it after the page has loaded, however, or it will overwrite the page.

For example, the following:

```
<p>one</p>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<p>two</p>');</script>
<p>three</p>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<p>four</p>');</script>
```

Will be displayed in the browser as if the static HTML source code were:

```
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p>
<p>four</p>
```

---

**typeof**

On a side note, the typeof operator returns one of the following string values:

```
    'undefined'
    'null'          // For browsers that support ECMAScript 6+
    'boolean'
    'number'
    'string'
    'function'
    'object'
```

The initial if statement could be refactored as follows:

```
Instead of this               Use this                     Or this
-------------------           -----------------            ------------
typeof(val) != null           val !== null
typeof(val) != false          val !== false
typeof(val) != NaN            typeof val == 'number'       !isNaN(val)
typeof(val) != undefined      typeof val != 'undefined'
```

Not sure if you need all of those tests though. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: If I'm right `document.write(res)` should overwrite the actual document not append the value to it.

Comment: @Eineki: I see what you mean. It depends on how it's used. If it's used after the page has loaded, it will overwrite the page. I updated the answer to reflect this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use Firebug... do you know any useful tutorial? For example I want to print Hello: <script type="text/javascript> console.log("Hello!")</script>

Comment: [Basic firebug tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/firebug-tutorials.php). In short, install the Firebug extension, open Firebug (F12 key), and click on the "Console" tab. You should see all messages that are sent to the console (errors, warnings, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
function print(){
    var val = {1, 2, 3};
    var res = showVariable(val);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = res;

   //if the target is an input :
   document.getElementById("myDiv").val = res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can output to an element:

HTML:

```
<div id="log"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function print(value) {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to the .innerHTML property if an element. Like so:

```
<div id="output"></div>

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = val;
```

Comment: Or use PRE tags if you want easy new line support

Answer (score 0):

You can try `document.write();`

```
function print(){
        var val = {1, 2, 3};
        var res = showVariable(val);
        document.write(res);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are correct. But for a beginner , it might be confusing . 
Let me break them into steps:

Problem: Lets say you want to collect the value from a text box and print it into the body of HTML.

- Step 1: Declare anything with an id 'result' (or anything)
- Step 2:
  Collect from text box into a variable.
- Step 3: Print it using
  innerHTML

```html
<html>
<body>

Hi everyone

<p id="result"></p>
<textarea cols="40" id="SearchText" rows="1"></textarea>

</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Submit!</button>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var result = document.getElementById("SearchText").value;
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'hello' + result;
}
</script>

</div>

</body>
<html>
```