# How to view my JavaScript in a browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting out with JS and I was wondering how it's possible to show the outcomes of my code?

Here is a small peice of test code I want to use but when viewed in a browser the page is blank:

```
if ( 11 > 10 ) 
{
   console.log("You made it!")  
}
else 
{
   console.log("You have just died!")    
}
```

I was wondering how it's possible to render my code the same way this website does:

http://repl.it/languages/JavaScript

Comment: Do you want to show the javascript code in browser as it is?

Comment: You need to open the development tools (F12 on most browsers, or you'll find it in the menu), there you'll find the console with your output.

Comment: This is a fairly complex question that's probably not well suited to SO.

Comment: For a simple example like yours you can also replace `console.log` with `document.write` because it has a single output.

Comment: @isherwood: Complex? Writing to the page is beginner stuff.

Comment: Wait, that has to be a joke, right @isherwood? That was funny.

Comment: Obviously it's not clear what aspect of the example page the OP is looking to reproduce. Early answers mentioned seeing output in the browser console. My understanding was that the OP wanted a more full-featured JS authoring tool. No jokes here, just a lack of clarity in the question.

Comment: @isherwood: I think people are trying to read too deeply into this question. The "outcome" of a `console.log()` is having the text printed to the console. Now OP wants to see it printed to the page instead.

Comment: A semicolon and a pipe walked into an underbar....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to do this instead:

```
document.write( "text" ) //de ...or:
document.writeln( "text" )
```

The more elegant way is to create a DOM element and to write into that, for example:

Create an element like `<div id="console"></div>` in your HTML ( or do this with JS also ), then:

```
function debug_output( text ) {
    document.getElementById( "#console" )
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
            'beforeend',
            '<span class="debug_output">' + text + '</span><br/>'
        );
        //de thanks to @cookiemonster for the .appendChild fix
}
```

---

Since you say you want pure text in the browser, I am first showing you how *not* to use `console.log` but to write directly to the browser.

Again, you will want to write into into the DOM. The second example I gave lets you do that, and perhaps style or place your debug output.

**Completed solution, with the above "more elegant" way:**

```
if ( 11 > 10 ) {
   debug_output("You made it!")  
} else {
   debug_output("You have just died!")    
}
```

Comment: thank you! I knew about document.write but I just wasn't using it properly! :)

Comment: `.appendChild()` doesn't accept HTML. It expects a DOM node. To append HTML like that, you'd use `.insertAdjacentHTML()`

Answer (score 1):

You're printing some values to the console; thus you need to use the developer tools installed on the browser of your preference.

For example https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

If you want to show the content within the html itself, then you need to insert a DOM element into your document.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

if ( 11 > 10 ) 
{
   container.innerHTML ="You made it!";  
}
else 
{
   container.innerHTML = "You have just died!";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azTX4/3/

Comment: I think he wants to show the code in browser as it is.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to view the output as pure text in the browser when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're trying to do... you could alert the user

```
alert(MESSAGE);
```

Or you could set the value of a DIV:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = MESSAGE;
```

More examples here:

[Print value returned by a function to screen in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590378/print-value-returned-by-a-function-to-screen-in-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

If you can wrap you code into particular function then you can append your javascript code inside the `pre` tag, and finally into body, something like this.

```
var myJsCode = function () { 
    if ( 11 > 10 ) {
       console.log("You made it!")  
    }
    else {
       console.log("You have just died!")    
    }
}

document.write('<pre>' + myJsCode + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I didn't vote, but take a look at your answer. It doesn't make sense. If you'd simply bother to test it out for yourself, you'd see that it's entirely wrong.

Comment: you can't capture the output from the console.log calls inside a function and using it as a string

Comment: I'd like to hear an explanation from whoever gave this +1. Now I *do* need to down vote it.

Comment: " how it's possible to render my code." +1 The question is ambiguous, this is a valid answer as it renders the code to the page

Comment: @Austin: So in your mind `document.write("<pre>my code</pre>")` would be a valid answer. The question is clear enough, but sometimes we need to read more than just the title.

Comment: @cookie monster, I just wanted show how he can show javascript code as it is in html.

Comment: @cookiemonster yes. If you look at the range of answers it's obvious it was unclear what was being asked. I myself was going to link to firebuglite because I thought op was looking for an in page console.